# Converting a math expression (String) to usable variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing, equations

I am trying to make an iPhone-app that does the Monte Carlo simulation on
equations given by the user. I want the user to be able to input something like:
"2x+(y^2)" and then recieve a result.

Is there a way to parse this string and get usable variables that i can do calculations on (a library u know of perhaps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [compiler tools](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/). although it might be a bit bloated, it is easy to write any "language" in it even if its just for simple mathematical expressions.

Comment: so u dont know of any free allready made framework i can use?

Comment: @user1033619: compiler tools are free